# Flash Zoom in Issue

Tags: php, html, css, flash, actionscript

In header I have placed a Flash banner. Zoom in and out (Ctrl + and -) is not working for the flash banner. Can this be fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have NoScale set on the stage you can use :

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE
```

Then add in a rescale event listener:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onStageResize)
private function onStageResize(e:Event):void {
    var widthScale:Number = stage.stageWidth / 500; // width of your swf
    scaleX = scaleY = widthScale;
}
```

This needs to be added to the .fla file in order to work.

Comment: Hi @Kyle, Thanks for the reply. It looks like I have lost the .FLA version of the banner. Now I am left with only .swf which we created few years back.

Comment: Then you could try the param tags and the embed object `<param name="scale" value="exactfit" /> <embed ... scale="exactfit" />` There are other attributes as well, like `scaleto` but I forget the rest. Not sure if it will work, but it's at least worth a try.

Comment: FYI, you should probably disable the Zoom options in Flash's context menu as well.  Once a user Zooms in, the NO_SCALE option gets turned off and nothing turns it back on.  Zoom Out and Zoom All do not restore the NO_SCALE option, and the Zoom 100% option is available only in the development environment.  It's a terrible bug in the way Flash handles zooming.